# Saving data to plist per object or person

Tags: ios, iphone, object, save, plist

I am trying to save data to the plist in my app per person, but it save it to everyone, so for example if I have a field for eye color and I enter Brown in the textfield for John Doe, it save Brown for everyone else as well, is there a way to save this info per person in the app instead using plist? I have had no luck trying:

```
-(NSString *)pathofFile{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsfolder = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [docsfolder stringByAppendingFormat:@"data.plist"];
}
```

Here is the code I have in my view did load:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self loadPerson];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *filepath = [self pathofFile];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:filepath]) {
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
        Drinfo.text = [array objectAtIndex:0];
        [array release];
    }

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:) name: UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:app];
```

and here is what I have as part of my saveperson method:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[array addObject:self.Drinfo.text];
[array writeToFile:[self pathofFile] atomically:YES];
[array release];
```

Comment: Some code would be really helpful. It sounds like you've got a fairly basic bug in the code that builds the data structure to go into your plist, and we could probably fix it very easily if we could see it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `plist` just create a `NSDictionary` for each person inside the `plist` and add the colour string to that. The steps would be something like

1. Open up the `plist` from file, set it to be a `NSDictionary` and make sure its a `mutable copy`.
2. Create a new `NSMutableDictionary` and add any attributes to that e.g. eye colour.
3. Add that `mutable dictionary` to your `plist` `dictionary` with the key set to the persons name
4. Save the `plist`